# Autocomplete Service Issue in Restricted Google API Key for React Native Android App

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, google-places-api

I've encountered an issue with using the Autocomplete service of the Place API after applying a Google API key restriction to my Android application using Android Restricted Key.

When the key restriction is enabled, the Autocomplete service doesn't function correctly. However, the map displays without any issues. On the other hand, as soon as I remove the key restriction, the Autocomplete service starts working normally for all queries.

I would like to understand why the Autocomplete service doesn't work when the key restriction is enabled, even though the map works correctly within the same application. Any insights or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello! Have you tried using a separate key for each different APIs? https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices

Comment: @Yrll Yes, I have tried using a separate key for each API. However, when I add the restriction to the second key for the Place Autocomplete API, the service still doesn't work

Comment: I believe it would be better for you to file a support case so that Tech Support agents can take a look at your project, and you can discuss more on how you were restricting your API keys. You can do it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support

Comment: In React Native, when I attempted to apply Android restriction using the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete, it didn't work as expected. However, I found a solution by using the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places, where the restriction worked correctly. Thank you @Yrll for your assistance in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem by using the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places. In React Native, when I attempted to apply Android restriction using the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete, it didn't work as expected. However, with the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places, the restriction worked correctly